# Accessing array elements by internal data index and order

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

This algorithmic problem is a bit too complex for me:

I have an NumPy array of data which is internally indexed in a peculiar way. The data is an output of two arrays spliced together (which I don't have), with distinct ordering. I set the parameter `max` to be a positive integer, and the data output has the index format

```
[ 00 10 20 ... max0 11 12 ... max1 22 23....max2 33....max max ]
```

The parameter `max` determines the output of the array (i.e. the length of the array) and the ordering.

For several examples, for `max=2`, the data is of the order

```
[00 10 20 11 21 22]
```

Setting `max=3` gives

```
[00 10 20 30 11 21 31 22 32 33]
```

And `max=4` is

```
[00 10 20 30 40 11 21 31 41 22 32 42 33 43 44]
```

And so on.

I would like to write an algorithm to make a list/array of only the `3x` values, i.e. the values with first index 3. That is, I would only like to access *certain* data values, organized by the first index.

However, this is determined by the parameter `max`. As you can see, this determines where the datum is placed by the array index. My only idea is to make some sort of sorting tree, but I am not sure how to execute that with this `max` parameter.

Comment: The only pattern I see is `[(00 10 20 30 40)(11 21 31 41)(22 32)(33 43)(44)]` which is (number of elements in each set) `[(max-0)(max-1)(max-2)(max-3)...(max-n)] where n <= max` each set is `11` more than the last set and each number in each set is offset by `10`. The only catch I see is that no number can exceed 'max*11' but that doesn't explain why the second set (zero indexed) doesn't have 42 in it. Maybe someone can use this as a starting point. It's the best answer I've got

Comment: @SirParselot Sorry, there's a typo. There should be a `42`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This list comprehension (or iteration) produces the indexs that you show

```
[[j*10+i for j in range(i,max+1)] for i in range(max+1)]

max=2: [[0, 10, 20], [11, 21], [22]]
max=3: [[0, 10, 20, 30], [11, 21, 31], [22, 32], [33]]
max=4: [[0, 10, 20, 30, 40], [11, 21, 31, 41], [22, 32, 42], [33, 43], [44]]
```

These lists of lists can be flattened.  But this arrangement may make it easier to think about the problem.

Or is it more useful to generate tuples:

```
In [134]: [[(j,i) for j in range(i,max+1)] for i in range(max+1)]
Out[134]: 
[[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0)],
 [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)],
 [(2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2)],
 [(3, 3), (4, 3)],
 [(4, 4)]]
```

It isn't clear what you want to do with these numbers or indices, but here's an example of putting them in a 2d array:

```
In [150]: dlist=[[j*10+i for j in range(i,max+1)] for i in range(max+1)]
In [151]: ilist=[[(j,i) for j in range(i,max+1)] for i in range(max+1)]

In [152]: import itertools

In [155]: M=np.zeros((max+1,max+1),int)
In [157]: for (i,j),d in zip(itertools.chain(*ilist),itertools.chain(*dlist)):
    M[i,j]=d

In [158]: M
Out[158]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [10, 11,  0,  0,  0],
       [20, 21, 22,  0,  0],
       [30, 31, 32, 33,  0],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44]])
```

The 1st 5 numbers go in the 1st column, 2nd 4 in the next, etc.

`itertools.chain` is one way of flattening a list of lists.

The layout of `M` looks like a lower-triangle.  There's a `numpy` function to generate those indices:

```
In [176]: np.tril_indices(5)
Out[176]: 
(array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32))
```

So I could have filled `M` with:

```
data =  np.dot([10,1],np.tril_indices(5))
M[np.tril_indices(5)] = data
```

Digging into the code of `tril_indices` I find that the starting point is a mask of 1s generated by:

```
I=((np.arange(max)-np.arange(max)[:,None])<0).astype(int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```